# Use .ASPX file as a Server-Side code to be called via AJAX by HTML/Javascript Client

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, active-directory

There are tools that are used by several thousand employees at my job.  They are currently stored on SharePoint 2010 (to be upgraded to 2016 very soon) in a document library.  Essentially, we're using SP2010 as a web server so we didn't have to charge a huge expense to our business unit for our own web server.

These tools are all based in HTML and JavaScript.  However, I'm trying to automate the collection of data points that the user is currently inputting manually.  To do this, I found that the best way would be to query the LDAP which is always going to be Server-Side code since there is no way to query the LDAP via the browser.  Below, you'll see the JavaScript that I have and the ASPX file that I have (minus the header that sharepoint automatically creates).  I'm sending an AJAX call over to the ASPX file with some data in the URL that will be needed to get the remaining data from the LDAP.  However, what I'm getting back seems to be literally ALL of the code that is being stored by the browser versus the ONE JSON variable that I want.

First the JavaScript:

```
var ldapUserName;
var employee = {};
var ADSystem = new ActiveXObject("ADSystemInfo");
ldapUserName = ADSystem.UserName;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://my.url.where/i/am/storing/getEmp.aspx?username=" + ldapUserName,
    success: function(data) {
                employee = data;
                alert(employee);
             },
    error: function() {
            alert("Connection Failed");
           }
    });
```

---

Next, the ASPX file (minus the SharePoint header that's automatically added)

```
<% 
Option Explicit
Response.LCID = 1043
%>
<!--#include file="jsonObject.class.aspx" -->
<%
Dim username 
username = Request.QueryString("username")
empDemo(username)
Public Function empDemo(username)

'Create the Array that will be passed
Set JSON = New JSONobject

'Employee specific information
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & username)

JSON.Add "empNum", objUser.sAMAccountName
JSON.Add "fName", objUser.givenName
JSON.Add "lName", objUser.sn
JSON.Add "fullName", objUser.displayName
JSON.Add "ext", objUser.telephoneNumber
JSON.Add "title", objUser.title

JSON.Write()

End Function
%>
```

Notice that I'm pulling in a file which helps the VBScript work with JSON variables.  That file can be [found here](https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON).

Again, what getting back seems to be quite literally all of the source code of the ASPX file.  What I need is to only get back the JSON variable.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your server does not know what an "aspx" file is. It thinks it is a text file and so its just returning the text of your file.

I am not sure how you would fix this as I am not familiar with Sharepoint. As Sharepoint is a document management system, It appears sharepoint is doing what it was built for. Storing documents and then allowing people to download them. There appears to be no interpreter on the Sharepoint servers for "aspx" files.

This URL might provide help in enabling this if it is even possible: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/828810/how-to-enable-an-asp.net-application-to-run-on-a-sharepoint-virtual-server

Comment: Are you sure?  Because I tried it on a different server (Windows Server 2012) running IIS 8.5 and I got error 500 when it makes the AJAX call.  I'm getting the feeling that there's something wrong with the variable that's taking the RequestString.  The content of that RequestString should be this syntax:  `CN=(numbers),OU=!(text),DC=(text),DC=(text),(text)`    To me (the novice), that kinda looks like it should be an object and not a regular variable (Dim).  Am I right?

Comment: I plugged your code into an old classic asp server I had and I got an error where you call GetObject("LDAP://" & username). Are you sure you are implementing that call correctly? You might take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/900182/5660649) for more instructions on implementing an LDAP call.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know the first thing about querying the LDAP till a few days ago when I started researching.  Very quickly I came across [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.08.heyscriptingguy.aspx) where I picked up this code.  After a bit of research (because the code blocks aren't labeled, I found out that it was VBScript.  I'll take a look at your article, though to see if I can pick up something.

Comment: Ok, I just reviewed that code and it seems like it's extremely overkill.  When I ran straight .vbs files locally, they spit back information just fine... I had other people do the same and they spit info back just fine.  As soon as I write it up in a .asp file and put it on t his server... it doesn't work.  One of my biggest problems with that other thread is that I don't really understand much of the code.  Are you sure that I should be doing something that fancy?

Comment: well... in 30 minutes my day will come to a close.  So I'll pick this up again  next week.  Thanks for your help @birwin.  However, I'm still completely stuck... Even with the updated code.